# Как получить индекс столбца при редактировании ячейки в Gtk.TreeView в C#?

Tags: c#, gtk

Есть `Gtk.TreeView`. В нём `ListStore store`. Ячейки в нем созданы как:

```
CellRendererText cell = new CellRendererText
{
    Editable = true
};
cell.Edited += Cell_Edited;
```

Пытаюсь сделать редактирование ячеек следующим образом:

```
private void Cell_Edited(object o, Gtk.EditedArgs args)
{
    Gtk.TreeIter iter;
    store.GetIter(out iter, new Gtk.TreePath(args.Path));
    store.SetValue(iter, COLUMN_INDEX, args.NewText);
}
```

Но никак не пойму как получить `COLUMN_INDEX`.
Перекопал кучу всего, но никак не пойму как сделать так что бы введённый текст сохранялся. Кто-нибудь знает как это работает?

Comment: [Пример](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/gtksharp/widgets/treeview-tutorial/#editable-text-cells)

Comment: С этого я начал. Там столбец задаётся вручную.

Comment: Если нужен прямо индекс то похоже без [такого костыля](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25949223/3907965)  ни как.

Comment: Этот костыль видел тоже. Но заставить работать не получилось.